# Python - Setting Class Attributes during Object instatiation(construction)

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have a class with an attribute which has to be set only once (let us say via a command line parameter). From there on it is not to be changed.

```
class Example(object):
    _classattribute = None
```

I am doing this by reading the command line param, and passing them as parameters during object construction. Depending on the classatribute, I return a different object Type.

```
class Example(object):
    _classattribute = None
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, attribute=None):
        if not cls._clsattribute:
             if not attribute:
                raise ValueError('class attribute not set')
            cls._clsattribute = attribute
        if cls._classatribute == condition1:
            cls._instance = Type1(cls._classattribute)
        if cls._classatribute == condition2:
            cls._instance = Type2(cls._classattribute)
        return cls._instance


class Type1:
    def __init__(self, property):
        self.property = property

class Type2:
    def __init__(self, property):
        self.property = property
```

During the object construction, for the very first time:

```
eg1 = Example("This is type1 attribute")
```

Subsequent construction of the object:

```
eg2 = Example()
```

Is this a good approach I can't say. It feels too explicit to me. Besides it is similar to the Borg, shared state pattern, except for the one time setting of the class attribute `_claassattribute`.

Any form of critique/feedback/thought/suggestion is welcome.

Comment: My take on this is that `__new__` should always return an object of the class, `None` or raise an exception. While what you do works, there is no reason to use a `class` if it can never return an instance of its own. Just use a function that returns either a `Type1` or a `Type2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something of a personal design choice, but my take on this is that `__new__` should always return an object of the class or `None`. In your code, there is no reason to use a `class` if it can never return an instance of its own. What you probably want ressembles a factory that returns either objects of `Type1` or `Type2`.

```
def get_type_factory(attribute):

    if attribution == condition1:
        return lambda: Type1(attribute)
    elif attribute == condition2:
        return lambda: Type2(attribute)
    else:
        raise ValueError

# Can be used like so
factory = get_type_factory('foo')

type_object1 = factory()
type_object2 = factory()
```